# Marker obstructing the location name in google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have created a marker for some location but the problem is , the marker keeps obstructing the location name i want the marker to go beneath the location name without changing the current zoom level.Is there any option that can be added in the constructor

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              //options
             });
```

Thnx

Example https://jsfiddle.net/vng1pbkf/

Comment: Please add your code from jsfiddle in question here.

Comment: Only option I see is `title` which comes as a tooltip when you hover over marker.

Comment: The only option is the marker's `position`, which you'd have to change.  Alternatively you come up with this approach, where you give your icon an offset from its location, and draw a little polyline connecting the marker's position to its icon: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2016/05/05/travel/what-to-do-36-hours-in-southeast-london.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to reduce the size of your marker image.
sample code:

```
var image = {
url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
// This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
// The origin for this image is (0, 0).
origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
// The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat: 25.2523934, lng: 55.3336367},
  map: map,
  icon: image
});
```

}